# python tkinter overrideredirect; cannot receive keystrokes (Linux)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python tkinter application which I want to run full screen. When I uncomment overrideredirect, the window manager (Gnome, Linux) will not be able to forward keystrokes to the application anymore.

(fragment, python)

```
# make it cover the entire screen
w, h = master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()
self.root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
self.root.focus_set() # <-- move focus to this widget
self.root.bind('<Escape>', self.root.quit())
#self.root.overrideredirect(True)
```

I've found the window::or package for Tcl/Tk, which is supposed to resolve this bug. How would I go about installing this, and would it be possible to use it from within my python application?

http://www.binarism.com/tk/window/or/

http://www.binarism.com/tk/window-or-0.1.1.tgz

Comment: some info here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/How%20Tkinter%20can%20exploit%20Tcl/Tk%20extensions

Answer (score 4):

This works for the use case where you're using overrideredirect to get fullscreen, which is somewhat common:

```
#self.root.overrideredirect(1)
self.root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

Comment: "fullscreen" isn't the same as setting the overrideredirect attribute.

Comment: Heads-up if you're using `overrideredirect()` or `-fullscreen` to go full-screen: the former should encompass the entire "display" - all monitors including areas that might not be on any monitor, same area that is captured with a full screenshot.
The latter only takes over the screen it's on - so normally one monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to enter the callable `self.root.quit` instead of `self.root.quit()` when you do the binding to avoid calling the function. when you will press Escape the callable will be called (I know I know) with an event argument. If `self.root.quit()` does not accept any argument: use lambda: `self.root.bind('<Escape>',lambda e:self.root.quit())`