# Tkinter overrideredirect no longer receiving event bindings

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tinter Toplevel window that I want to come up without a frame or a titlebar and slightly transparent, and then solid when the mouse moves over the window.  To do this I am using both `Toplevel.overrideredirect(True)` and `Toplevel.attributes('-alpha', 0.75)`.  I am binding the `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events to a function for this.

These all work when tried separately, but when I have the overrideredirect set to True, the bindings for the mouse entering and leaving no longer works.  The binding calls  when I click on the window, and then  when I move the mouse, but not when the curser enter or leave the window.

I have also tried binding these to a Frame, but with no further luck.

```
toplevel = Toplevel(root)
toplevel.overrideredirect(True)
toplevel.attributes('-alpha', 0.75)
toplevel.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: mouseMovement(command='enter'))
toplevel.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: mouseMovement(command='leave'))
def mouseMovement(command):
    print('Callback: ' + command)
    if command == 'enter':
        toplevel.attributes('-alpha', 1)
    elif command == 'leave':
        toplevel.attributes('-alpha', 0.75)
```

I have tried using the answer to the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886280/python-tkinter-overrideredirect-cannot-receive-keystrokes-linux), but this results in a window that has all the standard OS decorations, but the close, minimise, and enlarge buttons are simply disabled.  Is there a way where I can get rid of the titlebar, but still keep my bindings?

Comment: Just a comment on your code style: How come you do `lambda x: mouseMovement(command='enter')` when `command` is a positional argument of `mouseMovement`?  Doing `lambda x: mouseMovement('enter')` would work just fine.

Comment: That's simply the way I prefer to write it.  I didn't think it affected the code at all.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I was just curious.

Comment: Would it be more pythonic for me to have positional arguments without `command=`?

Comment: Yea, I would say so.  When people see `parameter=value`, they think of keyword arguments.  But your function is expecting positional arguments.  So, it is a little inconsistent.  But, like I said above, it won't affect the operation of the code.  It's merely a style thing.

Comment: What platform? Is this on OSX?

Comment: Seems to be working fine on Windows 7.

Comment: Well it seems to be working fine on Windows 10 too.

Answer (score 3):

On X Windows this can be handled using appropriate Extended Window Manager Hints to request the window manager to decorate the toplevel the way desired. This sounds like a splash screen window so 'splash' is likely to be appropriate here. For this use the wm_attributes [-type](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.html#M19) parameter eg:

```
toplevel.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
```

will have the toplevel decorated as for a splash screen dialog which usually means no title bar. If you apply this to an already mapped window, you will need to withdraw and re-map (call wm_deiconify) to get the window manager to apply its settings for the new hint type.