# Remove titlebar without overrideredirect() using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working with Tkinter and Python 2.7 on Linux and I was wondering if there was a way to remove the `TK()` window border frame and title bar without using `overrideredirect(1)`.

I have my own close button and `overrideredirect(1)` presents me with a few issues that I can't accept:

- GUI always on top
- can't iconify then deiconify properly
- no keyboard input so can't type into fields (see [python tkinter overrideredirect; cannot receive keystrokes (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886280/python-tkinter-overrideredirect-cannot-receive-keystrokes-linux))

I can't use `attributes("-fullscreen", True)` as the titlebar and borders remain.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The window decoration is all handled by the window manager so what you are trying to do is find a way to tell the window manager to decorate your window differently from a standard application window. Tk provides `overrideredirect` to have the window manager completely ignore this window but we can also use [Extended Window Manager Hints](https://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472629520) to declare the intended use of this toplevel window to the window manager. This is done for instance for tooltip and splashscreen windows to allow the manager to provide minimal decoration and possibly special animations.

In your case, adding a 'splash' hint should do what you want

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
```

You will need Tk 8.5 or above for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is this for use on Linux, Windows or Both? I'm currently on Windows using Python 3.5 and Tkinter 8.6 and I get this error:

`_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"`_

Comment: This is amazing - just tested it on Linux and it works perfectly! (so far)

Comment: The `-type` option is only relevant to X as it is a system used by X Window managers. TIP 359 has the details (http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/359.html). You can check `root.tk.call('tk','windowingsystem')` for "x11" and use that to avoid using this feature on other systems.

Comment: @D'Arcy I got the same error, no idea how to solve :(

Comment: @uniqueNt Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/a/30819099/291641 can help you on Windows if you need to modify the windows style of an overrideredirect Tk window.

Comment: There are lots of window decoration questions and answers. I revisit the subject a couple times a year. After a few years I finally found this answer that works like a charrm :)

Answer (score 4):

You must give your root window name before your command.

Like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true')
root.mainloop()
```