# Windows without decorations

Tags: python, tkinter

With this test code on python 3.6.3

`tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')` returns `'8.6.6'`
My OS is Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 3.6.7, but I want my code to be crossplatform.
I use the console to run the script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def valid(*args):
    print("Dans valid", nom.get())
    root.quit()

root = Tk()

rootW = 300
rootH = 200
x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - rootW)//2
y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - rootH)//2
root.geometry(f'{rootW}x{rootH}+{x}+{y}')

mainFrame = ttk.Frame(root,  padding="5")
mainFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

nom = StringVar()
nomEntry = ttk.Entry(mainFrame,  width=20,  textvariable=nom)
nomEntry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(E))
ttk.Label(mainFrame, text="Inscription").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainFrame, text="Votre nom").grid(column=1,  row=2)
ttk.Button(mainFrame, text="Validation", command=valid).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)

for child in mainFrame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

nomEntry.focus()
#root.update_idletasks()
root.overrideredirect(1)

root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

I want to use a tkinter window that removes all window manager decorations from that window with `overrideredirect()` method.

In this case, I don't have any more decoration, but I am no longer able to access the `Entry` field, while the `"Validation"` button is operational and exits the window.

If I comment the line `root.overrideredirect(1)` everything works normally, with decoration.

I tried adding the line `root.update_idletasks()`, but it doesn't change my problem: it's ok but with decorations.

How do I get an operational window without decorations?

Comment: _"In this case, i don't have any more decoration, but i'm no longer able to access the input fields."_ Do you mean you're unable to use the entry field, `nomEntry`?

Comment: While above code is simple, you can simplify it more, try to narrow down your code better using [mcve] for improving your question.

Comment: _"How do I get an operational window without decorations?"_ How exactly is the window in the code that you've provided _not_ operational?

Comment: Are you on OSX?

Comment: In linux, window decorations can be removed without using `overrideredirect`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529600/python-tkinter-remove-titlebar-without-overrideredirect

Comment: tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')  give '8.6.6'   And python 3.6.3 and my os is Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 3.6.7

Comment: Do you mean you're unable to use the entry field, nomEntry? **yes**

Comment: I don't think I'm having any trouble with the `nomEntry` using the above code on python 3.6.3, Tk 8.6.6 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

When I run (with IDLE) on 3.6.4, tk8.6.6, Win 10, I see an undecorated window with two labels, an entry box with focus, and a button.  When I enter "this is a test" , and click the button, I see "Dans valid this is a test" printed in the shell.  I do not see any problem.

The [NMT tk 8.5](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) doc claims that `.update_idletasks` is needed, but it seems not for this code with tk 8.6 on windows.  It also says "This method may not work on some Unix and MacOS platforms."  Does this apply to you?  If you are on MacOS, you are probably running 8.5 and possibly a buggy older 8.5 release that could be updated.

The [official tcl/tk 8.6](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M56) doc gives a bit more techinical detail, and also mentions that behavior is system dependent (though I do not understand the detail): "Some, but not all, platforms will take notice at additional times."

Comment: tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')  give '8.6.6'   And python 3.6.3 and my os is Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 3.6.7

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution, which is in any case valid on linux (to be tested on windows and OsX)

```
root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
```