# Python - hiding title bar breaks key binding

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

If I include either 
**win.attributes('-type', 'dock')** 
or
**win.overrideredirect(True)**
i can hide the title bar of my gui but the left key bind stops working. How do i hide the title bar but still keep my key binding?

```
from tkinter import *

def leftKey(event):
    print ("Left key pressed")


win = Tk()

win.geometry("600x400")
#win.attributes('-type', 'dock')
#win.overrideredirect(True)
win.bind('<Left>', leftKey)
```

Comment: It works fine in Windows 7 when `win.overrideredirect(True)` is called.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting... I'm running this on Raspian and no joy

Comment: found another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529600/remove-titlebar-without-overrideredirect-using-tkinter using ```win.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')``` but this method also breaks the key binding

Comment: ***running this on Raspian***: More interesting, which **Window manager** are used? Does this answer your question? [tkinters-overrideredirect-prevents-certain-events-in-mac-and-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582637)

Comment: Desktop session: LXDE-pi, XDG current desktop: LXDE, Window manager: Openbox. I will have a look if this tkinters-overrideredirect-prevents-certain-events-in-mac-and-linux can help me

Comment: @stovfl devilspie works nicely, the window shows the title for milliseconds and then devilspie strips it away. Thank you

Comment: Cosider to close the question as duplicate